# Perfomance Issue in Active Reports 6

Tags: c#, report, activereports

I am using active reports 6 for displaying reports.
And if we have lots of pages in the report then report is not displaying until all pages are loaded.

```
code :

ActiveReport ar = new ActiveReport();
ar.DataSource = lstDataContainingLargeRecords; // this list contains around 3000 records.
ar.Run();
```

I want to display first page immediately in the report and then other pages should be loaded in background.

Please give any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the Run(boolean) method and set its syncDocument parameter to true. You can get the code snippet example [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/topic3805.html).